# sum specific columns in matlab vectorized

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a big matrix lets say 100000x13.
I need to sum specific columns of this matrix.
For example:

```
matrix = [0.70  0.30    0   0   0.15    0.21    0.58    0.06    0.00    1.00    0   0   1.00;
      0.70  0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    0.07    0.06    0.00    0.80    0   0   1.00;
      0.70  0.00    0   0   0.00    0.00    0.58    0.06    0.00    1.00    0   0   0.94];

inputVect = [4 4 3 2];
idx2 = cumsum(inputVect);
idx1 = [1 idx2(1:end-1)+1];

result = (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(1):idx2(1)),2)) + (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(2):idx2(2)),2))+(1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(3):idx2(3)),2)) + (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(4):idx2(4)),2));
```

The thing is inputVect needs to be a function argument that I don't allways know the size. And because of the size of the matrix I should also avoid for loops. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: since `matrix` is a 2D array, this code already gives errors, because you are summing different size arrays together. In your example `sum(matrix(:,idx1(1):idx2(1)))` has size 4x1, `sum(matrix(:,idx1(3):idx2(3)))` has size 3x1 and `sum(matrix(:,idx1(4):idx2(4)))` has size 2x1. So I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you fix your example code AND provide an example (but obviously smaller) array for `matrix`?

Comment: Sorry my bad: result = (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(1):idx2(1)),2)) + (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(2):idx2(2)),2))+(1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(3):idx2(3)),2)) + (1-sum(matrix(:,idx1(4):idx2(4)),2)); Corrected now. Thanks

Comment: Can do what is requested above?